# Is it possible to be admitted to an astrophysics graduate program with a finance background?

Tags: graduate-admissions, physics, changing-fields

Does anyone know if any of the US universities (or European universities that teach classes in english) enrol students into their Masters program for Astronomy/Astrophysics without having a science background?
I am a 2nd yr graduate student about to finish my MBA in finance and info sys mngt. I work as a Business Analyst. However my dream has always been to pursue Astrophysics but was never able to, due to various circumstances. I am however at a point in my life that I feel burnt out being on this auto-pilot mode (mindlessly working a stable job to pay my bills) and wish to go back to school to study Astrophysics.
Do I have to thus start back from a Bachelors level and major in Physics in order to apply at a Masters program or are there universities that enroll candidates like me?
Any advice will be helpful - thanks in advance!

Comment: How much experience you have with astrophysics will change this answer dramatically. Normally, a computer scientist who wishes to switch to medicine is unlikely to have the biology/chemistry background to make the jump directly in. The same applies in this case from Finance to Astrophysics, which are very far apart on the knowledge spectrum.

Comment: Studying one subject is one thing and getting food on the table is another. Do you want to study Astrophysics or do you want to work as an Astrophysics scientist? Because having an MBA gives you much more chances of getting employment. On the other hand nothing stops you from studying Astrophysics on your free-time or part-time (e.g. Open University)

Comment: Please avoid abbreviations like "info sys mngt" which are not contextually obvious. I guess that stands for... information systems management?

Answer (score 1):

*I have no direct experience with Europe, so this will be US-based.*

A graduate program in astrophysics will definitely assume a lot of background in undergraduate physics (classical mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum mechanics, relativity) not to mention all the math (calculus, linear algebra, differential equations). It simply takes too many years to teach everything up to the masters level from scratch. Note that unlike some professional schools, grad schools in the natural sciences generally assume you spent a good deal of your undergrad studying the subject in question (or something close to it).

Also one thing to keep in mind is that in the US (unlike much of Europe) astrophysics graduate programs are mostly PhD programs: the first couple years focus more on coursework and give you a masters at the end, and the remaining 3-4 years focus mostly on research and conclude with your thesis defense. One generally has to apply to the full PhD program -- very few programs admit students just for the masters. Thus in most cases you have to be judged ready/willing/able to do a PhD to be admitted. And since natural science PhD's pay you money to be a student, they do really want to make sure they're getting committed people.

All this said, the thing to do is look up schools that have astro programs -- there are actually fewer of them than you might think -- and see what they say. Some might have more flexibility for students getting a late start in the field, and some might have alternate compromises available, especially for people who have a good deal of education already.<sup>1</sup>

In any event I would recommend dabbling a bit in astrophysics before taking the plunge into doing it full time, based on how little experience you say you have with it. Skim some undergrad level textbooks, or take a free online course. It may be just like you imagined, but it may very well be different from your expectations. Or you may find your interest in the subject is satisfied by such self-learning without dealing with making a living from it.

Finally, I'll leave you with an example of an alternate career choice to mull over, just to show that the broad field of astrophysics takes a broad range of talent and backgrounds. [Bill Paxton](http://www.kitp.ucsb.edu/members/PM/paxton), after doing quite well at Adobe, retired and went into computational astrophysics, using his CS knowledge to help write one of the most widely used stellar evolution codes, among other things. The lesson is that astrophysics isn't intentionally exclusive, but you may have to work hard to get into it.

---

<sup>1</sup> My department, for example, is experimenting with a post-baccalaureate program that runs separately from its main PhD program.